# Description Logic symbols in LaTeX

Tags: fonts, math-mode, symbols, packages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to look up a symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol)

I need to get symbols of [description logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Description_logic) names looking like at the picture:

[image: SROIQ]

Should I use some special font for this purpose, and which one? Or is there any special LaTeX package? Any other ideas?

Comment: `\mathcal{SROIQ}`?

Comment: If the question isn't considered duplicate, you can add an answer for better reusability.